# Error while inserting username and password in login android app using phpmyadmin database

Tags: php, android, phpmyadmin, nullpointerexception

So when i tried to insert the username and password which is already inside the phpmyadmin database it gets toast output which is in the onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) and when i saw the Logcat it says

```
09-30 19:25:34.535 18067-18364/com.example.devarsh.googlemapsbustracker E/Volley: [7269] NetworkDispatcher.processRequest: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
at com.example.devarsh.googlemapsbustracker.MainActivity$4.getParams(MainActivity.java:91)
    at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:464)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:275)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:249)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:94)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:123)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:131)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
09-30 19:25:34.552 18067-18067/com.example.devarsh.googlemapsbustracker E/MainActivity: com.android.volley.VolleyError: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

I already tried to hardcore the Username and password inside my php script but it didnt work for me

Here is the Android Code :

```
package com.example.devarsh.googlemapsbustracker;


import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
private Button btnlogin;
private EditText User_name, Pass_word;
private static String URL_LOGIN = "http://192.168.50.127/Android/login.php";




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnlogin = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    User_name =  findViewById(R.id.username);
    Pass_word =  findViewById(R.id.password);


    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Login();
        }
    });


    isServicesOK();
}

private void Login(){

    String URL = "http://192.168.2.8/parul/login.php";
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            if(response.trim().equals("success")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Selection_Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Unsuccessfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(error));
            System.out.println("VolleyError start : " + error + ": End of VolleyError");
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

            user = User_name.getText().toString().trim();
            pass = Pass_word.getText().toString().trim();

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("UserName", User_name.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put("PassWord", Pass_word.getText().toString().trim());

            return params;
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}


public void isServicesOK() {
    Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: checking google services version");

    int available = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if(available == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        //everything is fine and user can make map request
        Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: Google Play Services is working");
    }
    else if(GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(available)){
        //there is an error but we can fix it
        Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: An error is there but we can fix it");
        Dialog dialog = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, available, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST);
        dialog.show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "We cant make maps request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

}
```

And here is my php script which is used to get the username and password from the app to check weather it is exist in database or not and this code is for Localhost database using Xampp :

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","users");
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$username = "parul";
$password = "parul1998";

$query = 'SELECT id FROM logintb WHERE username = "'.$username.'" and password = "'.$password.'"';
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('error: ' .mysql_error());

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){

    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "error";
}


?>
```

The below code is used for testing the app with the live 000webhosting :

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","id7263189_root","dev@1234","id7263189_logintb");
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$username = $_POST["UserName"];
$password = $_POST["PassWord"];

$query = 'SELECT id FROM logintb WHERE username = "'.$username.'" and password = "'.$password.'"';
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('error: ' .mysql_error());

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){

    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "error";
}


?>
```

I don't know how to solve that invoke virtual method :

```
com.android.volley.VolleyError: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

FYI I am testing this in real device. but when i hardcore the username and password in the php file and run the app in emulator it works fine but when i tried on the real device it's show the Login Unsuccessful Toast.

When i try to run this application in Emulator it works fine without any error but when i try it in the real device it shows that error from OnerrorResponse(VolleyError error) which is a toast of Login Unsuccessful

I am newbie in the android app development so need some help from anyone who can solve this problem for me.

My activity_main.xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:background="@color/blend"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/imagelogo" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="252dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/User_name"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="186dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/Pass_word"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="81dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="112dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="@string/login" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: **Warning:** Never store passwords in clear text! _Only_ store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: Will try=>  first clean your project then and uninstall application from real device then install again in real device

Comment: the code you have added in question is updated?, i mean it is that you are using currently?, exact same?

Comment: @SurajVaishnav i have updated my code and when i try the above updated code in the emulator it works fine with no error in Logcat but when i run it in the real device and click on the button its says the Login unsuccessful toast and that  `com.android.volley.VolleyError: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference` error in the Logcat

Comment: is your app crashing?

Comment: add your activity_main code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            User_name =  findViewById(R.id.username);
            Pass_word =  findViewById(R.id.password);
            user = User_name.getText().toString().trim();
            pass = Pass_word.getText().toString().trim();

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("UserName", user);  // direct use user
            params.put("PassWord", pass);  // direct use pass

            return params;
        }
```

update your `getParams` method find views inside it, it's not better approach but why don't you give it a try.

Remove

```
android:importantForAutofill="no"
```

and

```
android:ems="10"
```

from edit text

Comment: nope still getting the Null Exception error which is mention above

Comment: done you can see and tell me what is wrong here and i tried the above answer but didnt work in the real device but when i tried in the Android emulator it works like charm. whats wrong with the real device. and in real device the logcat says that Null Exception error

Comment: You have added manifest code accidentally,  please  post activity_main.xml code

Comment: user direct variable value in params.put, check my answer i have updated it, and let me know what happens

Comment: Nope still not working in the real device with the same error but still working in the emulator just fine

Comment: thank you all i have solved my problem and posted the answer below

Answer (score 1):

```
com.android.volley.VolleyError: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

This would happen because the `EditText` you're trying to get the text from is empty. But the interesting point is that you said it works on emulator.

The only solution we-I can suggest is using and getting strings from the `EditText`s as follows:

```
String user = User_name.getText().toString().trim();
String pass = Pass_word.getText().toString().trim();
```

Declaring variables inside the `Map` might probably help.

Comment: You can however set a breakpoint for those lines of codes to see if it's getting the strings or not.

Comment: but where should i declare the above answer of yours in my code? is it inside the onCreate method?

Comment: Like I said, try to use it inside the map.

Comment: and how should i connect the localhost database with the android app which is in my real device. Like will it work if i connect both my localhost system and my real device to the same wifi network?

Comment: Solved my problem and posted the answer below